# Quiero imprimir en una tabla el texto que escribo en un input al presionar click por fuera, tengo este código el cual me sale indefinido

Tags: php

Quiero imprimir en una tabla el texto que escribo en un input al presionar click por fuera, con el eventListener al escribir una a una las letras me sale, indefinido

```
<script>

    let inputValue = document.getElementById("hallazgoSistema").addEventListener("input", () 
    => {
       document.getElementById("tHallazgo").innerHTML = inputValue;
        console.log(inputValue);
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes almacenar primero el input en una variable para poder acceder a sus propiedades.

```
 let inputHallazgo=document.getElementById("hallazgoSistema");
inputHallazgo.addEventListener("blur", function() {
      
       document.getElementById("tHallazgo").innerHTML = inputHallazgo.value;

    });
```

Comment: excelente muchas gracias

Comment: Amigo como puedo seguir agregando mas datos